# NESTED LOOPS COUNT

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are K Nested Loops & N is given to us

```
j=0;
for i1: = 1 to N
    for i2: = i1+1 to N
        for i3 := i2+1 to N
            ....
                .....
                    ...... so on
                        for iK:= i(K-1)+1 to N
                            j++;
```

Every loop  starts with previous loop variable +1, except for the first loop. 
What will the value of j be after all loops execute? There is an exact formula for this. I also want to know how to get to that formula?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Well.. for N<K , answer is zero.. for N=k, answer is 1,

Comment: for K=2 its N*(N-1)/2... for K=3 its summation of (N-r)*(N-r+1)/2 from r=2 to N-1.. after that i am stuck :/

Comment: start with small values, like 1 loop only. What's $j$ then? Add the second loop. Then a third one. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: It is from hackerrank actually.. the formula is (N-(k*(K-1)/2))CK . But i want to know how to reach that formula..
the link to the problem is:  https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack41/challenges/arias-loops/

Comment: **Caution**, the ranges of the for loops that you give and those in the contest aren't the same, hence the fomulas will differ.

Answer (score 1):

The nested loops enumerate all tuples $(i_1,i_2,\cdots i_k)$ such that $0<i_1<i_2<\cdots n$. The number of these is known to be a binomial number $$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

Indeed, this is the number of ways to choose $k$ distinct numbers among $n$ (you can do it in $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$ ways) counting only the permutation that is in increasing order (i.e. divide by $k!$).

Comment: What would be the answer if the ranges were according to the question..
i.e
for i1: = 1 to N
    for i2: = i1+1 to N
        for i3 := i2+2 to N
            ....
                .....
                    ...... so on
                        for iK:= i(K-1)+K-1 to N
                            j++;
????

Comment: @Looper: you know it, don't you ?

Comment: I know the formula.. but how to get to it.. like you did to the previous problem?

Comment: NO.. I got it.. Thanks!! :D